# CLR webservice call times out at 100 seconds

Tags: sql, timeout, clr, webrequest

I have not found this answered anywhere.  I have a CLR function that exectues a webmethod call of my .NET application (.asmx).  The web service successfully executes when called directly but when called via the CLR it times out after 100 seconds with the following error:

```
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "fn_ExecuteReport":
System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
System.Net.WebException:
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at DD.WebServices.WebExec.ExecuteReport(String ddBotID, String serverKey, Int32 ddUserID, String reportReportTypeList, String deliverToUserList)
   at ExecuteReport.GetResult(Int32 userID, SqlString reportList, SqlString deliverToUserList)
```

I have increased the web service proxy timeout in fn_ExecuteReport without effect:

```
WebExec svc = new WebExec();<br/>
svc.Timeout = 3600000;  // set timeout to 1 hour<br/>
result = svc.ExecuteReport(userID, reportTypeList.ToString(),
                           deliverToUserList.ToString());
```

I want to capture the returned result so executing the webservice asynchronously is not a solution.  Where else might I override timeout settings for the SQL CLR call?  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Here's the code for the function. I'm able to execute the webservice, the timeout only occurs when executing via the CLR.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_ExecuteReport]
(@UserID int, @ReportTypeList nvarchar(max), @DeliverToUserList nvarchar(max)) 
RETURNS [nvarchar](255) 
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER AS EXTERNAL NAME [MyCLRLib].[ExecuteReport].[GetResult]
```

I've tried both synchronous and asynchronous calls to the web service in the CLR function and both end up with the 100 second timeout.  Here's both calls that I've tried:

Synchronous:
WebExec svc = new WebExec();
svc.Timeout = 3600000;  // set timeout to 1 hour
result = svc.ExecuteReport(userID, reportTypeList.ToString(), deliverToUserList.ToString());

Asynchronous:
WebExec svc = new WebExec();
IAsyncResult result = svc.BeginExecuteReport(userID, reportTypeList.ToString(), deliverToUserList.ToString(), null, null);
result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
retStr = svc.EndExecuteReport(result);

Comment: that's only the stub for the function. How about posting the code...

Comment: I added the guts of the function above. I've tried making the web service call both sync and async without success.  Thanks for having a look.

Comment: " I added the guts of the function above " - where?

Comment: The two sections above labeled "Synchronous" and "Asynchronous" are the guts of my "ExecuteReport" c# class that the stub calls.  The first is a sync call so I tried changing it to the async call but the CLR still times out after 100 seconds so it's not this code that is timing out.  The CLR function has to execute a WebRequest to retrieve the webservice data and it's this WebRequest that appears to be timing out.  I'm not sure how/where this retrieval code is generated.

Comment: For a few reasons (one of which being the timeout issue) I decided to build a little console app to execute the web service rather than use SQL CLR. I'd still like to know how to invoke long-running web service calls via SQL CLR so I'll buy a beer for anyone who can tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message suggests that the timeout is originating at SQL Server.

Have you tried updating your SQL Server statistics (or rebuilding indexes)?

Can you post the code of your CLR function?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Here's the code for the function...not much to it. Again, I'm able to execute the webservice, the timeout only occurs when executing via the CLR.            ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_ExecuteReport](@UserID [int], @ReportTypeList [nvarchar](max), @DeliverToUserList [nvarchar](max))
RETURNS [nvarchar](255) WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
ASEXTERNAL NAME [MyCLRLib].[ExecuteReport].[GetResult]